# Use of unresolved identifier 'parameters' in Swift

Tags: php, ios, iphone, json, swift

So I get this error when trying to run my script

> Use of unresolved identifier 'parameters'

And here's the code to get a CSRF token then log the user in

```
    var username = usernameField.text
    var password = passwordField.text

    var token = String()
    var parameters = String?()

    //Get CSRF token
    Alamofire.request(.GET, "https://localhost/api/csrf")
        .responseJSON{(request, response, data, error) in
            var jsonParse = data as NSDictionary
            var responseJSON = JSON(jsonParse)

            if(responseJSON["success"]) == false{
                println(responseJSON["error"])
            }
            else{
                let token = responseJSON["data"].string

                let parameters = [
                    "user": username,
                    "password": password,
                    "csrf": token
                ]
            }

    }

    Alamofire.request(.POST, "https://localhost/api/login", parameters: parameters)
        .responseJSON{(request, response, JSON, error) in
            println(token)
            println(JSON)

    }
```

I don't see why I can't access `parameters` out of the scope considering that I already initiated it like so

```
var parameters = String?()
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You defined your *parameters* outside your request-Block. Inside your request-Block you define a constant variable, which is only accessible inside that block. Therefore remove that **let** and just write:

```
parameters = [
                "user": username,
                "password": password,
                "csrf": token
            ]
```

And I think the second request should be made after you get the response of the first request? If so, put the second request inside the callback of your first request.

EDIT: the same problem goes for "token", so do the same here.

Comment: the same applies to token